# EntityManager create native query vs persist and injections

Tags: jpa, ejb, sql-injection, entitymanager

Is `createNativeQuery()` safe against SQL injection if used as in:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public User register(User u) {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT r1_register(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        short i = 0;
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getUsername());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getPassword());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getName());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getSurname());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getEmail());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getBirthdate());
        query.setParameter(++i, u.getPhoneNumber());
        int id = (int) query.getSingleResult();
        if (id != 0) u.setIduser(id);
        return u;
    }
}
```

`r1_register` is a stored function that performs an INSERT and returns the id of the newly inserted user. Would this be equivalent:

```java
public User register(User u) {
    em.persist(u);
    // get the last inserted id (user id must be @Generated)
    em.flush(); // user id set here
    return u;
}
```

`u` is in both cases filled by the user. Finally is a transaction initiated by default ?

EDIT: The routine:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `r1_register`(username VARCHAR(45),
                _password VARCHAR(45),
                _name VARCHAR(45),
                surname VARCHAR(45),
                _email VARCHAR(45),
                _birthdate DATE,
                phone_number VARCHAR(10) ) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
-- Adds a new user.
    -- START TRANSACTION; -- Begin a transaction -- NOT ALLOWED
    -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969875/
    IF r1_check_unique_username(username)=0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `hw1_db`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `birthdate`, `phone_number`)
        VALUES (username, _password, _name, surname, _email, _birthdate, phone_number);
    -- see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5939840/281545
    -- The drawback to this approach is that you cannot go back and use
    -- ids wasted because of failed attempts to INSERT IGNORE in the event
    -- of a duplicate key. Shouldn't be a problem for us as we check.
    -- /Transaction
    -- IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN
    -- ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows updated/inserted/deleted
    --  COMMIT; -- Finalize the transaction
    -- ELSE
    --  ROLLBACK; -- Revert all changes made before the transaction began
    -- END IF;
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Comment: Generally, parameterized SQL constructs (e.g. `PreparedStatement`) escapes special characters by default and in so doing, you're protected against vanilla SQL injections

Comment: @kolossus: yes I am asking about the JPA api - does for instance `persist(Entity e)` internally escape String fields of the Entity it persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what `r1_register` is actually doing. If it just saving the user and nothing else, than yes, they are equivalent because that's what `EntityManager#persist` is doing. But if the DB function is performing some security checking or writing to other tables, than you need to implement it in JPA too. Btw code for inserting `User` and obtaining the ID should be

```
public User register(User u) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(u);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    int id = u.getId();
    return u;
}
```

But you don't have to call `EntityManager#flush` if you need that id after the `register` method is called, flush is performed by the end of every transaction.

Comment: So they both guard against sql infection ? Also they both initiate a transaction ? Mycode is as seen. Also `e.getId();` ? There is no e variable

Comment: Sorry, I meant `u`. Well, `EntityManager` certainly protects you from SQL injection. And no, transaction is iniatiated by entering to the method in `EJB` bean or through `em.getTransaction().begin();`.

Comment: You are wrong I am afraid `em.persist(u);` with or without flush _does not set the id_ - `System.out.println("USER id: " + u.getIduser());` prints 0. I still wonder if injection is prevented - I am surprised they don't mention it in the docs. Also I am not still sure there is transaction going on - could you provide some links ?

Comment: EM wouldn't even insert your entity into DB if there is no active transaction. It depends in which context you are calling it - is method `register` part of EJB bean?If yes, you've got transaction out of the box, if not, than you need to begin and commit it by yourself.

Comment: And for SQLi, you are really safe with EM unless you are concatenating variables to a SQL quries.

Comment: So is `persist()` internally escaping String fields of the Entity ? I 'd rather have some reference on this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to use transactions. And for the reference, I am sorry but I can't find anything but I am absolutely sure that EM escapes it - it would be quite useless if the JPA wouldn't protect from SQLi.

Comment: Edited my question to display the routine - would your `em.getTransaction().begin();...em.getTransaction().commit();` work the same with the `createNativeQuery` way ?

Comment: +1 for getting me to the right track with the id - it had to be annotated with @Generated to (`em.persist()` would work but I needed flush to get the id written in the entity - weird). Last thing I need you to tell me. Could your answer be modified so the transaction is declarative (ie I do not `begin` and `commit` manually) ?

Comment: You would have to use EJB bean or switch to CDI 1.1 to get declarative transactions, you unfortunately won't achieve this in JSF bean.

Comment: So `register()` is not executed inside a transaction ?

Comment: No, like I said you need either EJB or newest CDI in order to get declarative transactions.